# Copy executable to live system

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have Java Maven project in Eclipse. Sometimes I need to copy binary with all libraries and configuration files to live system. Is it right place to ask Maven about it?

Should I use `package` goal for this reason. Should I use any plugin? Where I should define remote system sftp logins and paths?

Comment: Where do you want to assemble the files in the final deployment?

Comment: I need to copy files via `sftp` to remote machine - `192.168.1.3`,  `/opt/` folder.

Comment: Then you need to assemble them locally first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Answer (score 0):

For building a .jar with all dependencies and a main-class attribute, you can use the maven plugin `maven-assembly-plugin`

You can use it like this in your pom-file:

```
<plugin>                                                        
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>              
    <configuration>                                             
        <archive>                                               
            <manifest>                                          
                <mainClass>package.mainClass</mainClass>           
            </manifest>                                         
        </archive>                                              
        <descriptorRefs>                                        
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>                                       
    </configuration>                                            
    <executions>                                                
        <execution>                                             
            <id>make-assembly</id>                              
            <goals>                                             
                <goal>single</goal>                             
            </goals>                                            
            <phase>package</phase>                              
        </execution>                                            
    </executions>                                               
</plugin>
```

Inside the `<build>` and `plugins` of course :)

Comment: Creating a "runnable" JAR is just half of the story isn't it?

Comment: @GeroldBroser yeah, but I did not really understand the other part, the question isn't really clear... :(

Answer (score 0):

See [How to Create an Executable JAR with Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) with pros & cons for the different options:

- Manual Configuration
- Apache Maven Assembly Plugin
- Apache Maven Shade Plugin
- One Jar Maven Plugin
- Spring Boot Maven Plugin
- Web Application with Executable Tomcat

Use the [Wagon Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) to copy/upload the so created "executable" JAR wherever you want.

Comment: Wagon is intended for Maven, not general use.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen [Wagon](https://maven.apache.org/wagon/) itself, yes. That's why I mentioned and linked the Wagon _Plugin_. Not using that for general use would be silly.